# I cannot save data to my SQL database using C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I am trying to save the numbers into a SQL Server database table (locally) but I get an error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column

My code:

```
private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     { 
         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\fn1965\Desktop\Work\TESTDB\NumDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

         conn.Open();
         string insert_query = "INSERT into [NumericTable] (Num1, Num2, Total) VALUES (@Num1, @Num2, @Total)";

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_query, conn);

         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num1", textBox1.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num2", textBox2.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", textBox3.Text);

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         MessageBox.Show("Record saved");

         conn.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("EROR:"+ ex.ToString());
     }
}
```

Table schema

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to insert NULL into a column that is defined in the database as "do not allow nulls."

Comment: It means you are passing a null value to a column in your table which does not except `NULLS`

Comment: Look at the schema information for the table NumericTable. Do you have other columns that are not set from your query? Are these columns allowed to get NULL values?

Comment: Provide the table structure, hope you have some primary key and not setting value during insert.

Comment: @FrancisNaval Add to your post, put up the table schema (All Column Names with Data Types)

Comment: I uploaded the picture.  I have only small table schema

Comment: @FrancisNaval It appears your `primary key column` was not created as an `Identity column`, so it looks like it isn't `auto-incrementing` the `Id` column, so on Insert it is failing because you haven't supplied an Integer. Take a look at this article (https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-define-an-auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection and SqlCommand are both IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block. You may want to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). I suggest [edit]ing your question to add the [tag:sql-server] tag. It's better to provide a script for your table definition than an image.

Comment: @RyanWilson after I added the identity on the ID it was working. Thank you very much.

Comment: @FrancisNaval You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: Side note: if these columns contain **numerical** data - **why on earth** are they defined as `nvarchar(50)` ?? Use the **most appropriate** datatype - always, no exceptions. And `nvarchar(50)` is certainly ***NOT*** the most appropriate datatype to store numerical values! Use `int`, `bigint`, or `decimal` - whatever suits your needs

Comment: I'm upvoting this question for the simple reason that it's the *first* question along these lines I've read where it *wasn't* vulnerable to SQL Injection.  Kudos on the dynamic parameterization.

Answer (score 2):

You can see in the image that the column `Id` is the only one that does not support null values. Since the column is not identity and as you are not providing a value on your insert, then the INSERT fail with the given exception. This code will work (only if there isn't a record with Id = 1 already):

```
        string insert_query = "INSERT into [NumericTable] (Num1,Num2,Total, Id) Values (@Num1,@Num2,@Total, @id)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num1", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num2", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I assume that this is obviously not the desired fuctionality. What you should do is either set the Id column to identity = true or set a value on the insert.

I also encourage you to not use `AddWithValue` method since it can lead you to some undesired problems. You can read more here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: this will not work if there is a record with an `ID = 1` as it would violate the primary key constraint. I don't imagine that was intentional, just being nit-picky. If the OP desired to insert their own primary key, they would need to either query their table first to find a unique  integer or modify their query to find a unique integer value and use it as  the primary key. In any case, using an Identity auto-increment is much easier.

Comment: I recommend not using this method of data access st all, and learn Entity Framework instead! :)

Comment: @RyanWilson you are right i will make the corresponding edit

Comment: @NicoRiff Thank you for updating your answer. :)

Comment: @CaiusJard it is matter of what everyone likes to use. I prefer to use Dapper as I personally do not like EF. If OP wants to have more control over DB and go on writing queries I will definitely go with Dapper. But that is my preference.

Comment: Sure, Dapper, EF, nHibernate, LINQ to sQL, datasets.. ANYTHING is better than newbies writing sql in strings in button click handlers. At least he didn't concatenate a load of injection prone sql together.. but still, I always feel that newbies starting out using databases like this is like writing 3D games by going straight to opengl/trying to write an engine in assembler, or making web service calls by opening a tcp socket and pushing the bytes of an http header etc down the wire. Newbies should use abstractions, and take the engine apart when they know what they're doing/have a reason

Answer (score 2):

That screenshot you took of your table columns design; get back to that, then click the id column, look in the Properties grid for Identity Specification (might need to expand it) and set it to Yes. Set other properties relevant to your needs and save the table.

Borrowed from another SO question:

[image]

There are ways to do this from script but they're generally longer/more awkward than using the UI in management studio.

This will (should) change th column so it auto inserts an incrementing number into itself when you insert values for other rows. Someone else has posted an answer as to how to insert values for it yourself but my recommendation to you as a learner is to use auto increment to save the additional needless complication of providing your own primary key values